# How Do I Search Between a Date Range, Using the ActiveRecord Model?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, between

I am new to both Ruby and ActiveRecord. I currently have a need to modify and existing piece of code to add a date range in the select.  The current piece goes like this:

```
ReportsThirdparty.find(:all, :conditions => {:site_id=>site_id, :campaign_id=>campaign_id, :size_id=>size_id})
```

Now, I need to add a range, but I am not sure how to do the `BETWEEN` or `>=` or `<=` operators.  I guess what I need is something similar to:

```
ReportsThirdparty.find(:all, :conditions => {:site_id=>site_id, :campaign_id=>campaign_id, :size_id=>size_id, :row_date=>"BETWEEN #{start_date} AND #{end_date}")
```

Even if this did work, I know that using interpolation here would leave me subject to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I believe you can pass a Range object to ActiveRecord's find and get what you want:

```
ReportsThirdParty.find(:all, 
  :conditions => { 
    :site_id => site_id, 
    :campaign_id => campaign_id, 
    :size_id => size_id, 
    :row_date => start_date..end_date } )
```

Edit: If you're using  Rails 3 you can expect to use something similar to:

```
ReportsThirdParty.where( 
  :site_id => site_id, 
  :campaign_id => campaign_id, 
  :size_id => size_id, 
  :row_date => start_date..end_date)
```

For more information on Rails 3 Active Record queries check out:
 http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3